# Php Contact Form Reference error

Tags: javascript

I was following a tutorial on youtube about setting up a contact page and for some reason I'm getting an error message in the console saying submitForm is not defined when I press the submit. My issue is I got the same code to work on another website but when I copy the exact same code it doesn't work. Here's my js code:

```
function _(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
function submitForm(){
    _("mybtn").disabled = true;
    _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append( "n", _("n").value );
    formdata.append( "e", _("e").value );
    formdata.append( "m", _("m").value );
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open( "POST", "example_parser.php" );
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            if(ajax.responseText == "success"){
                _("my_form").innerHTML = '<h2>Thanks '+_("n").value+', your message has been sent.</h2>';
            } else {
                _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                _("mybtn").disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send( formdata );
}
```

and here is my php code:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['n']) && isset($_POST['e']) && isset($_POST['m']) ){
    $n = $_POST['n']; // HINT: use preg_replace() to filter the data
    $e = $_POST['e'];
    $m = nl2br($_POST['m']);
    $to = "skoolboi434@gmail.com";  
    $from = $e;
    $subject = 'Contact Form Message';
    $message = '<b>Name:</b> '.$n.' <br><b>Email:</b> '.$e.' <p>'.$m.'</p>';
    $headers = "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "The server failed to send the message. Please try again later.";
    }
}
?>
```

As you can see I defined the function but getting that error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how are you putting the javascript in your html? Directly in the HTML page in `<script>` tag or included as a resource?

Comment: The PHP is irrelevant, since you're getting a Javascript error.

Comment: There must be some problem with the way you're loading the Javascript. There's no way to tell what you've done wrong from what you've posted.

Comment: Is it a public website that you can give the URL for?

Comment: i'm loading the javascript in a separate js file, the website url is www.jewebdevelop.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what I did so I started over and rewatched the tutorial a few times and got it to work.